# why does this program not work?

Tags: java

As far as I could understand the following program make a polygon.But why does it not work? This takes arguments for drawPolygon function from another class.

```
package test1;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Sc extends JPanel {
    int[] xpoints=new int[10];
    int[] ypoints=new int[10];
    int npoints;

    public void method(int a[],int b[], int num){
        xpoints=a;
        ypoints=b;
        npoints=num;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        mc.fun();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Sc());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }  
}
```

This is the MainCLass.java

```
package test1;

public class MainClass {
    int x[] = {25, 145, 25, 145, 25};
    int y[] = {25, 25, 145, 145, 25};
    int npoints = 5;

    public void fun(){
    Sc sc = new Sc();
    sc.method(x,y,npoints);
    }
}
```

I came across this code but i don't know what is wrong with it.I am new to Java.Could someone please help me out.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please describe an expected behavior of your program?

Comment: You have 2 different `Sc` objects.

Comment: which main method are you running and why you think it doesn't work?

Comment: please give desired output... and what you are getting right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your code is really messy (and not easy to read) your problem is that you are adding a different instance of Sc to the Pane rather than adding the one you were drawing on:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new Sc());
```

Instead you have to add "this" which you can't do from a static method, but you can create an instance of Sc and initialize it with a method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Sc sc = new Sc();
    MainClass mc = new MainClass();
    mc.fun(sc);
    sc.initFrame();

}

public void initFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(this);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

You also have to take sc as an argument in your "fun" method (which then calls the "method" method from the sc object... again this could be done in only one class which would be a lot less confusing):

```
public void fun(Sc sc){
    sc.method(x,y,npoints);
}
```

This is still really messy, but at least it works now ;)